# How to create a symbol depicting Don Knuth?

Tags: symbols

The `marvosym` package has a symbol `\MartinVogel`, how to create a similar macro that shows Don Knuth?

Comment: Tikz may be? @HanSolo

Comment: @Raaja May the Tikz be with you!

Comment: thanks and a nice answer

Answer (score 10):

Converting https://openclipart.org/people/FS/1304882618.svg to tikz yields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\newcommand{\knuth}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.07ex,x=0.07ex,yscale=-1,xscale=1,baseline=-1.8ex]
\path[fill=black,even odd rule,line width=6.004pt] (10.8884,1.2280) .. controls (10.3532,1.2300) and (9.8253,1.3212) .. (9.3117,1.5767) .. controls (8.0463,1.8028) and (7.7927,2.6577) .. (7.2761,3.6492) .. controls (6.1499,4.6991) and (4.7714,5.6110) .. (4.3894,7.2160) .. controls (3.7079,8.6737) and (3.0261,10.2833) .. (3.3447,11.9312) .. controls (3.2020,12.1949) and (1.7766,12.4394) .. (2.4576,13.4255) .. controls (2.4982,15.0528) and (4.3665,15.7781) .. (4.7592,17.2819) .. controls (4.7293,16.8539) and (3.5900,15.1454) .. (3.5837,14.0809) .. controls (2.9499,12.7371) and (5.0696,12.0575) .. (4.9944,13.6281) .. controls (4.4494,14.9284) and (5.1217,15.9719) .. (5.5346,17.1329) .. controls (5.5373,18.4814) and (6.0980,18.9139) .. (5.8927,19.1365) .. controls (5.6874,19.3592) and (4.8856,19.8742) .. (4.6850,20.1476) -- (4.6811,20.1348) .. controls (3.9266,20.3658) and (3.4166,20.9130) .. (2.9294,21.4515) .. controls (2.4423,21.9900) and (1.9755,22.5208) .. (1.3214,22.7818) -- (1.3132,22.7851) -- (1.3054,22.7896) .. controls (0.7499,23.1036) and (0.1363,23.4195) .. (-0.2784,23.9772) -- (-0.0657,24.1353) .. controls (0.3017,23.6411) and (0.8735,23.3380) .. (1.4337,23.0213) .. controls (2.1535,22.7291) and (2.6443,22.1616) .. (3.1259,21.6292) .. controls (3.5415,21.1699) and (3.9490,20.7381) .. (4.4813,20.4940) .. controls (4.4194,20.6305) and (4.3743,20.7726) .. (4.3461,20.9186) .. controls (4.2325,21.5080) and (4.3889,22.1507) .. (4.7705,22.7331) .. controls (5.4231,24.2982) and (5.8904,25.9064) .. (6.2161,27.5650) -- (6.2179,27.5743) -- (6.2210,27.5832) .. controls (6.5775,28.6021) and (7.0271,29.5865) .. (7.4805,30.5557) -- (7.7205,30.4434) .. controls (7.2687,29.4778) and (6.8242,28.5033) .. (6.4734,27.5020) .. controls (6.1444,25.8298) and (5.6723,24.2053) .. (5.0121,22.6235) -- (5.0072,22.6120) -- (5.0002,22.6014) .. controls (4.6430,22.0624) and (4.5072,21.4828) .. (4.6063,20.9688) .. controls (4.7015,20.4746) and (5.0098,20.0343) .. (5.5788,19.7279) .. controls (5.3127,20.4245) and (5.4052,21.1378) .. (5.6660,21.7989) .. controls (5.9702,22.5703) and (6.4981,23.2837) .. (6.9645,23.8812) .. controls (8.0763,25.9856) and (9.5252,27.9180) .. (11.3917,29.4247) -- (11.3930,29.4258) -- (11.3944,29.4268) .. controls (11.7918,29.7312) and (11.9666,30.2843) .. (12.4036,30.6878) -- (12.5834,30.4932) .. controls (12.5570,30.4688) and (12.5318,30.4430) .. (12.5072,30.4164) .. controls (12.9876,30.6495) and (13.6498,30.5764) .. (14.3094,30.7498) .. controls (14.4889,30.8259) and (14.6555,30.7841) .. (14.8128,30.6592) -- (14.9968,30.7270) .. controls (15.0633,30.5463) and (15.1279,30.3658) .. (15.1929,30.1859) .. controls (15.4442,29.7658) and (15.6761,29.1814) .. (15.9072,28.6142) .. controls (16.4936,27.6246) and (17.2136,26.6735) .. (17.5933,25.5402) .. controls (17.9943,24.9073) and (18.3795,24.3030) .. (18.7350,23.6539) .. controls (19.0973,23.1900) and (19.4380,22.7094) .. (19.7784,22.2374) .. controls (19.7771,22.2389) and (19.7759,22.2405) .. (19.7746,22.2420) -- (19.7810,22.2338) .. controls (19.7801,22.2350) and (19.7793,22.2362) .. (19.7784,22.2374) .. controls (20.1713,21.7735) and (20.5136,21.2605) .. (20.7864,20.7143) .. controls (21.0153,20.5843) and (21.3236,20.0545) .. (21.2426,19.6877) .. controls (21.5070,18.3966) and (21.8815,17.1433) .. (21.9808,15.8150) .. controls (22.3319,14.4863) and (23.1706,12.9578) .. (23.1088,11.7197) .. controls (22.3306,10.6019) and (22.9023,9.0661) .. (22.0834,7.9154) .. controls (21.7298,6.2961) and (19.8795,5.9749) .. (19.2297,4.6258) .. controls (19.0862,4.0444) and (17.9810,1.4362) .. (18.0971,3.2596) .. controls (17.2334,2.8856) and (15.7769,1.7254) .. (14.4502,1.7107) .. controls (13.2783,1.6512) and (12.0658,1.2237) .. (10.8884,1.2280) -- cycle(11.1398,3.4532) .. controls (12.1732,3.4604) and (13.2997,4.3658) .. (14.4055,4.1901) .. controls (15.7055,3.8450) and (16.9379,5.3061) .. (18.1459,4.6032) .. controls (18.9481,5.3069) and (19.7368,6.0565) .. (20.2315,6.9692) .. controls (20.1906,6.9512) and (20.1490,6.9345) .. (20.1058,6.9207) .. controls (20.3663,8.6503) and (20.5760,10.5495) .. (19.6541,12.1192) .. controls (19.9573,12.3672) and (20.6434,12.6726) .. (21.1418,12.6593) .. controls (21.1148,12.7849) and (21.0855,12.9101) .. (21.0536,13.0343) -- (21.0528,13.0372) -- (21.0522,13.0402) .. controls (21.0066,13.2584) and (20.9624,13.4783) .. (20.9250,13.7005) .. controls (20.9199,13.6988) and (20.9149,13.6969) .. (20.9098,13.6953) .. controls (20.8338,13.2874) and (20.4925,12.9738) .. (19.7777,13.0623) .. controls (19.3876,13.1983) and (18.8554,13.3497) .. (18.3400,13.5509) .. controls (18.2726,13.5630) and (18.2054,13.5769) .. (18.1384,13.5942) .. controls (17.8177,13.6119) and (17.5310,13.7162) .. (17.2874,13.8793) -- (17.2830,13.8173) .. controls (16.1038,13.9000) and (14.9125,13.7069) .. (13.7086,13.6329) .. controls (13.6693,13.6145) and (13.6292,13.5986) .. (13.5890,13.5858) .. controls (12.2103,12.9831) and (10.1059,12.5825) .. (9.1131,13.9967) .. controls (9.4295,13.9589) and (10.0830,13.8439) .. (10.3260,13.9055) .. controls (9.9903,14.0350) and (9.7008,14.2347) .. (9.4827,14.4927) .. controls (9.3804,14.6138) and (9.2948,14.7479) .. (9.2278,14.8926) .. controls (8.2867,14.3441) and (7.3460,13.7741) .. (6.6006,12.9998) .. controls (6.7162,12.5245) and (6.8487,12.0537) .. (6.9509,11.5914) .. controls (6.7103,10.1871) and (6.7753,8.7708) .. (7.3138,7.4334) .. controls (7.6950,5.8574) and (9.1255,5.0929) .. (10.0604,3.8914) .. controls (10.4044,3.5654) and (10.7660,3.4505) .. (11.1398,3.4532) -- cycle(18.6828,4.7267) .. controls (18.7876,4.8013) and (18.8816,4.8913) .. (18.9676,4.9912) .. controls (18.8735,4.9018) and (18.7785,4.8136) .. (18.6828,4.7267) -- cycle(21.3574,12.9071) .. controls (21.4614,13.3774) and (21.6280,13.8407) .. (21.7076,14.3183) .. controls (21.5791,14.1086) and (21.3989,13.9346) .. (21.1751,13.8109) .. controls (21.2135,13.5723) and (21.2615,13.3339) .. (21.3115,13.0944) .. controls (21.3274,13.0322) and (21.3426,12.9697) .. (21.3574,12.9071) -- cycle(7.2462,20.1199) .. controls (7.2211,18.7073) and (6.1942,17.3984) .. (6.5226,15.9456) .. controls (6.2336,15.0679) and (6.3355,14.1800) .. (6.5298,13.3050) -- (6.5298,13.3050) .. controls (7.2850,14.0502) and (8.1993,14.5997) .. (9.0950,15.1218) -- (9.2246,14.8996) .. controls (9.0121,15.3639) and (8.9926,15.9380) .. (9.2422,16.5546) -- (9.2458,16.5634) -- (9.2507,16.5718) .. controls (9.6396,17.2357) and (10.3328,17.5026) .. (11.0615,17.5954) .. controls (11.7903,17.6883) and (12.5708,17.6163) .. (13.1889,17.5934) -- (13.2075,17.5927) -- (13.2253,17.5869) .. controls (13.9395,17.3524) and (14.4854,16.5248) .. (14.6527,15.6971) .. controls (14.7170,15.3788) and (14.7240,15.0572) .. (14.6513,14.7650) .. controls (15.2769,14.7370) and (15.9172,14.8067) .. (16.5708,14.7694) .. controls (16.2453,15.5476) and (16.3753,16.5158) .. (17.1814,17.0323) -- (17.1934,17.0399) -- (17.2066,17.0449) .. controls (17.8662,17.2906) and (18.7906,17.5694) .. (19.6476,17.5657) .. controls (20.0760,17.5639) and (20.4899,17.4910) .. (20.8423,17.2981) .. controls (20.8509,17.2934) and (20.8593,17.2883) .. (20.8678,17.2834) .. controls (19.9994,18.2854) and (19.5090,20.6531) .. (18.1799,19.3932) .. controls (18.0591,19.3512) and (17.9857,19.1090) .. (17.8382,19.3078) -- (17.8381,19.3078) .. controls (18.4968,20.1144) and (18.9870,21.9088) .. (17.3106,21.6671) .. controls (16.7012,21.8725) and (16.5075,22.2778) .. (16.5045,22.7401) .. controls (16.4973,22.6932) and (16.4866,22.6443) .. (16.4712,22.5926) .. controls (15.6737,23.0218) and (13.7318,22.0652) .. (13.6280,23.0428) .. controls (14.1753,23.5924) and (16.4346,23.9220) .. (16.5126,22.9203) .. controls (16.5610,23.4635) and (16.8206,24.0562) .. (16.9577,24.4868) .. controls (15.8939,25.6288) and (14.0964,24.7362) .. (12.9109,25.6550) -- (12.9108,25.6551) .. controls (12.8969,25.6510) and (12.8831,25.6464) .. (12.8691,25.6423) .. controls (12.4139,25.4603) and (11.9700,25.2428) .. (11.5528,25.0359) -- (11.5490,25.0339) -- (11.5451,25.0324) .. controls (11.0678,24.8326) and (10.6155,24.5676) .. (10.1875,24.2582) .. controls (9.6470,23.7577) and (9.1212,23.1785) .. (9.1812,23.4162) .. controls (8.7234,22.9812) and (8.2987,22.5076) .. (7.9066,22.0288) .. controls (7.8078,21.2743) and (7.2256,20.6673) .. (6.9426,20.1002)(6.6577,20.3855) .. controls (6.7976,21.3562) and (6.7681,22.1444) .. (6.7769,23.0982) -- (6.7085,23.0988) .. controls (6.8645,23.3181) and (7.0251,23.5288) .. (7.1802,23.7273) -- (7.1875,23.7366) -- (7.1930,23.7470) .. controls (7.6251,24.5659) and (8.1084,25.3571) .. (8.6471,26.1062) .. controls (8.5247,25.8242) and (8.6087,25.7009) .. (9.2443,26.1768) .. controls (9.9167,26.7566) and (11.5806,28.8631) .. (12.0797,27.2930) .. controls (11.8422,25.8454) and (10.2323,25.2672) .. (9.5151,24.0714) .. controls (8.8345,23.5023) and (8.2253,22.8390) .. (7.6809,22.1720) -- (7.6557,22.1412) -- (7.6517,22.1017) .. controls (7.5850,21.4488) and (7.2803,21.1575) .. (6.7279,20.1828)(6.4352,19.9071) .. controls (6.5567,20.7497) and (6.5123,21.9438) .. (6.5114,22.8121) .. controls (6.2760,22.4570) and (6.0629,22.0832) .. (5.9124,21.7017) .. controls (5.6291,20.9832) and (5.6995,20.3883) .. (6.0982,19.6698)(18.1666,13.5924) -- (18.1701,13.6192) .. controls (18.1691,13.6196) and (18.1681,13.6200) .. (18.1672,13.6204) -- cycle(14.1003,13.9350) .. controls (15.0638,14.0127) and (16.0370,14.1334) .. (17.0220,14.0960) .. controls (16.8518,14.2636) and (16.7129,14.4635) .. (16.6103,14.6808) -- (16.5987,14.5026) .. controls (16.1081,14.5343) and (15.6083,14.4979) .. (15.0999,14.4931) .. controls (14.9304,14.4915) and (14.7599,14.4934) .. (14.5886,14.5025) -- (14.5926,14.5789) .. controls (14.5837,14.5558) and (14.5741,14.5330) .. (14.5640,14.5105) .. controls (14.4764,14.3169) and (14.3409,14.1470) .. (14.1593,14.0151) .. controls (14.1411,13.9876) and (14.1215,13.9609) .. (14.1003,13.9350) -- cycle(20.9224,13.9749) .. controls (21.1890,14.0855) and (21.3858,14.2751) .. (21.5141,14.5123) .. controls (21.6603,14.7827) and (21.7138,15.1225) .. (21.6584,15.4854) .. controls (21.6486,15.5181) and (21.6384,15.5510) .. (21.6269,15.5841) .. controls (21.6201,15.6303) and (21.6138,15.6765) .. (21.6071,15.7227) .. controls (21.5611,15.8875) and (21.4934,16.0547) .. (21.4009,16.2207) -- (21.3954,16.2307) -- (21.3916,16.2415) .. controls (21.2501,16.6460) and (21.0151,16.9015) .. (20.7151,17.0657) .. controls (20.4152,17.2299) and (20.0454,17.2990) .. (19.6465,17.3007) .. controls (18.8547,17.3042) and (17.9586,17.0407) .. (17.3151,16.8021) .. controls (16.7750,16.4500) and (16.5985,15.8568) .. (16.6888,15.2944) .. controls (16.7313,15.3237) and (16.7733,15.3451) .. (16.8150,15.3596) .. controls (16.7412,16.0542) and (18.2968,16.8165) .. (19.0782,16.6450) .. controls (20.4054,15.5960) and (17.8833,16.3342) .. (17.6156,15.3659) .. controls (17.5005,15.3467) and (17.3842,15.3160) .. (17.2673,15.2944) .. controls (17.7061,15.0587) and (18.0790,14.5024) .. (18.3657,15.4128) -- (18.5492,15.4489) -- (18.8024,15.3236) .. controls (19.2785,15.1183) and (19.5254,13.9473) .. (19.7511,15.1249) .. controls (20.1922,15.1613) and (20.5529,14.8840) .. (20.7537,14.5211) .. controls (20.5779,15.1723) and (20.6813,15.8345) .. (20.3845,16.3550) -- (20.6147,16.4862) .. controls (20.9879,15.8315) and (20.8456,15.0925) .. (21.0372,14.4952) -- (20.8043,14.4204) .. controls (20.8694,14.2771) and (20.9102,14.1245) .. (20.9224,13.9749) -- cycle(10.5939,14.3012) .. controls (10.6665,14.3021) and (10.6790,14.4105) .. (10.5751,14.7217) .. controls (11.2487,14.0923) and (10.8907,16.0986) .. (11.8876,15.2793) .. controls (12.2000,14.4324) and (12.7346,15.0468) .. (13.2862,15.2112) .. controls (12.9690,15.3471) and (12.5798,15.5455) .. (12.4976,15.5037) -- (12.4975,15.5037) .. controls (11.7916,15.5270) and (11.8315,15.9559) .. (11.7373,16.2282) .. controls (11.4526,16.5481) and (13.3587,15.8505) .. (13.6041,15.3446) .. controls (13.6408,15.2969) and (13.6669,15.2579) .. (13.6854,15.2250) .. controls (13.8531,15.1747) and (14.0177,15.0393) .. (14.1735,14.7632) .. controls (14.2265,14.6856) and (14.2593,14.6064) .. (14.2754,14.5275) .. controls (14.2924,14.5573) and (14.3082,14.5880) .. (14.3226,14.6197) .. controls (14.4514,14.9045) and (14.4686,15.2706) .. (14.3930,15.6446) .. controls (14.2430,16.3872) and (13.7192,17.1361) .. (13.1548,17.3297) .. controls (12.5293,17.3537) and (11.7745,17.4192) .. (11.0950,17.3326) .. controls (10.4105,17.2454) and (9.8209,17.0124) .. (9.4844,16.4453) .. controls (9.1906,15.7112) and (9.3169,15.0994) .. (9.6850,14.6637) .. controls (9.7552,14.5807) and (9.8347,14.5043) .. (9.9222,14.4349) .. controls (9.4975,15.4182) and (10.3591,14.2982) .. (10.5939,14.3012) -- cycle(13.9873,17.4793) .. controls (13.8903,17.4809) and (13.7643,17.4875) .. (13.6044,17.4994) .. controls (12.4146,18.2154) and (10.6635,19.2717) .. (10.8069,20.9020) .. controls (11.2530,20.9451) and (11.9914,18.8110) .. (12.9956,18.3859) -- (12.9956,18.3859) .. controls (13.1486,17.9071) and (14.9250,17.4636) .. (13.9873,17.4793) -- cycle(16.9980,17.6554) .. controls (15.9121,17.8705) and (17.1911,18.0203) .. (17.4766,18.3673) .. controls (16.5747,18.9465) and (14.9079,19.3944) .. (13.7268,18.9370) -- (13.7267,18.9370) .. controls (13.7726,19.2936) and (14.1796,19.3676) .. (14.4233,19.5441) .. controls (14.8561,21.1804) and (17.3488,20.7605) .. (17.4949,19.1401) .. controls (18.7094,18.9607) and (17.5816,17.8975) .. (16.9980,17.6554) -- cycle(13.2125,21.1735) .. controls (12.6933,21.1800) and (12.1712,21.2373) .. (11.6711,21.3105) -- (11.6709,21.3105) -- (11.8225,21.4098) -- (11.9846,21.4759) .. controls (13.5450,21.5009) and (15.0950,22.4185) .. (16.6460,21.8438) .. controls (17.9863,21.0740) and (15.6488,21.4919) .. (15.1481,21.4735) .. controls (14.5429,21.2405) and (13.8801,21.1651) .. (13.2125,21.1735) -- cycle(18.8648,21.2575) .. controls (19.1380,21.2633) and (19.3966,21.8117) .. (19.6010,22.0363) .. controls (19.5914,22.0477) and (19.5821,22.0593) .. (19.5725,22.0707) -- (19.5692,22.0746) -- (19.5661,22.0788) .. controls (19.3834,22.3321) and (19.2014,22.5865) .. (19.0171,22.8384) .. controls (18.6779,22.6394) and (17.8700,23.5474) .. (17.3274,24.1102) .. controls (17.9418,23.3987) and (18.5160,22.6350) .. (18.5027,21.6322) .. controls (18.6239,21.3558) and (18.7457,21.2549) .. (18.8648,21.2575) -- cycle(19.0720,23.2684) -- (18.8932,23.4640) .. controls (19.5254,24.0421) and (20.3153,24.2979) .. (21.0805,24.5494) .. controls (21.8457,24.8009) and (22.5860,25.0481) .. (23.1534,25.5761) -- (23.1612,25.5833) -- (23.1700,25.5892) .. controls (24.0627,26.1866) and (25.1149,26.3711) .. (26.0094,26.8220) -- (26.1287,26.5855) .. controls (25.1885,26.1115) and (24.1522,25.9262) .. (23.3205,25.3709) .. controls (22.7017,24.8016) and (21.9232,24.5475) .. (21.1632,24.2977) .. controls (20.3979,24.0462) and (19.6514,23.7983) .. (19.0720,23.2684) -- cycle(18.5987,24.1680) -- (18.3703,24.3021) .. controls (18.8427,25.1068) and (18.9002,25.9485) .. (18.7596,26.7988) .. controls (18.7437,26.8951) and (18.7248,26.9915) .. (18.7041,27.0878) -- (18.5388,27.0336) .. controls (18.0785,28.4364) and (16.6779,29.2359) .. (15.8556,30.5241) -- (16.0789,30.6666) .. controls (16.7517,29.6126) and (17.9275,28.8576) .. (18.5510,27.6770) .. controls (18.3851,28.2311) and (18.1658,28.7780) .. (17.9552,29.3019) -- (17.9501,29.3143) -- (17.8970,29.6062) -- (18.1576,29.6537) -- (18.2059,29.3881) .. controls (18.5260,28.5922) and (18.8745,27.7277) .. (19.0209,26.8420) .. controls (19.1681,25.9518) and (19.1075,25.0347) .. (18.5987,24.1680) -- cycle(9.8664,27.6168) .. controls (10.2165,27.9805) and (10.5829,28.3441) .. (10.9477,28.6968) .. controls (10.5688,28.3546) and (10.2086,27.9938) .. (9.8664,27.6168) -- cycle(9.5385,28.4444) .. controls (9.1978,28.4529) and (8.8803,28.6022) .. (8.6320,28.8325) .. controls (8.2083,29.2257) and (7.9548,29.8431) .. (8.0197,30.4308) -- (8.2830,30.4017) .. controls (8.2289,29.9117) and (8.4530,29.3601) .. (8.8123,29.0267) .. controls (9.1715,28.6933) and (9.6344,28.5660) .. (10.1383,28.8825) -- (10.2792,28.6582) .. controls (10.0549,28.5173) and (9.8268,28.4513) .. (9.6069,28.4446) .. controls (9.5840,28.4439) and (9.5612,28.4438) .. (9.5385,28.4444) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\MartinVogel\knuth

\Huge\MartinVogel\knuth

\end{document}
```

[image]